# How to insert a script in JMeter to be run?

Tags: rest, jmeter

I have a webservice implemeneted by REST.

Is it possible to insert a script into JMeter to run some commands sequentially? If yes, how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter supports several scripting languages, from performance perspective it's recommended to use [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and Groovy as a language.

If your script is "light" and doesn't assume running in multiple threads you can consider Beanshell. [How to use BeanShell](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide is a good place to start for JMeter scripting.

If you could describe your use case in more details perhaps we might find the way to do it without scripting, JMeter is powerful and flexible enough.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just use scripting in [sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BSF_Sampler) or in [PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BSF_PreProcessor) in PostProcessor or Assertion. What kind of script and for what purpose do you want to run script?